# Bluetooth connection, JBL Flip3 to Mac Pro

Tags: bluetooth

I've read all the advise posted to connecting JBL Flip speaker to Mac Pro.
I'm not sure if this covers the new JBL Flip 3. Holding down the power button does not provide an alternating blue red light. The power button light stays white and Mac Pro does not detect the Flip 3. Any suggestions?

Also turned off all other BLT devises. Still no luck.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, pressing wrong button

Answer (score 2):

Try long-press on the bluetooth button on the Flip 3. That should make it discoverable in the Bluetooth preferences in the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Just turn the Flip 3 device on, make sure the Bluetooth is turned on for your MBP, then in the Bluetooth dropdown menu go to Bluetooth preferences. Now with the blue lit up power button on the Flip 3 if it's facing towards you, to the right there are three black buttons along the speaker mesh, press down the one with the Bluetooth symbol on it. Now it should pair...